# Curly braces missing after replace json data

Tags: postgresql

Following data in table dashboard_data. The column name is mr_data.

```
{"priority_id": "123", "urgent_problem_id": "111", "important_problem_id": "222"}
{"priority_id": "456", "urgent_problem_id": "", "important_problem_id": "333"}
{"priority_id": "789", "urgent_problem_id": "444", "important_problem_id": ""}
```

Query-

```
UPDATE
    dashboard_data
SET
    mr_data = replace(dashboard_data.mr_data,'urgent_problem_id','urgent_problem_ids')
WHERE
    mr_data->>'urgent_problem_id' IS NOT NULL;
```

Expected result:

```
{"priority_id": "123", "urgent_problem_ids": {"111"}, "important_problem_ids": {"222"}}
{"priority_id": "456", "urgent_problem_ids": {""}, "important_problem_ids": {"333"}}
{"priority_id": "789", "urgent_problem_ids": {"444"}, "important_problem_ids": {""}}
```

**Is there any way that during replace we get {} representation of data as shown in expected result.**

Comment: Expected result is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @SachiTekina Want to store multiple ids so is there any way that it can be achieved?

Comment: Then, should be an array: `"important_problem_ids": [222, 1111, ...]`

Comment: what type is the column mr_data?

Comment: @Jasen its type is json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Postgres 9.5 or newer.

You can use `jsonb_set` to add a proper JSON array with a new key, then remove the old key from the JSON (which is the only way to rename a key)

```
update dashboard_data
  set mr_data = jsonb_set(mr_data, '{urgent_problem_ids}', 
                          jsonb_build_array(mr_data -> 'urgent_problem_id'), true) 
                - 'urgent_problem_id'
where mr_data ? 'urgent_problem_id';
```

`jsonb_build_array(mr_data -> 'urgent_problem_id')` creates a proper JSON array with the (single) value from the `urgent_problem_id` that value is then stored under the new key `urgent_problem_ids` and finally the old key `urgent_problem_id` is removed using the `-` operator.

Online example: http://rextester.com/POG52716

---

If your column is not a `JSONB` (which it should be) then you need to cast the column inside `jsonb_set()` and cast the result back to a `json`